# Ignoring Git submodules inside submodules

Tags: git, jenkins

Scenario: We have 2 Repositories, RepoA and RepoB.
RepoA is added as a submodule inside RepoB. When i do git clone --recursive of RepoB , it clones the submodule RepoA as well. Now there are other submodules added inside of RepoA. Is there a way to ignore those Submodules which are present inside RepoA.

Comment: don't use the `--recursive` when cloning, after clone run `git submodule update`. This should give you only direct submodules without transitive ones

Comment: Can not eliminate the —recursive since it’s needed for other repositories.  Is there a way or file which can be used? For E.g. we use .gitsubmodules for adding the submodule. Something to ignore submodule , a file preferably

Comment: As Cubimon mentioned don't use `--recursive`. Iterate through each submodule and initialize them. `git submodule update --init <submodule>`

Comment: that is something I cannot eliminate. It’s a part of Jenkins plugin.

Comment: Write your own plugin.